# How to make changes to other person pull request in github?

Tags: git, github

We have a repository from which everyone has created a fork and make PR for features and bug.

I want to make changes into another person PR. One way I have seen is that I can login into github and go to that file in that PR, make changes and commit there.

But since I want to compile my changes locally, how can I do it?
Do I need to clone the other person's fork and then create a new PR?
What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: clone that person's fork, change to that particular PR's branch, make your changes and just git push them. Changes will show in original PR.

Comment: @Abhinav you can't push to someone else branch in github. It would have worked if the PR won't have been created from a fork but directly from the "common" repository

Comment: @Philippe I remember it being possible since github adds you contributor to newly forked repo? I can't say it 100% though. Otherwise the answer you've posted shall be a fallback :)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Not sure. I think it works only on an "Organisation" account and is not possible on a "normal user" account.

Comment: @abhinav this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a PR on the branch of the other person that he will merge or squash in its repository (that will update it's PR).

If you want to add more than one commit without creating a merge commit or even modify the already pushed history, the best thing to do is perhaps to push your branch in your repository and ask the dev to sync the branch (through a message in the PR conversation) used to do the PR with your branch. If he push the branch updated, that will update the PR.

FYI, you should know that GitHub has a feature that allows the owners of a repository to directly push in the branch used to to the PR if the one that created the PR checked the "Allow edits by maintainers" checkbox when creating the PR.